# Question about commercial mix concrete design

Tags: concrete

[image]

What should I do here? Drying the aggregates prior to mixing make sense to me but would it be costly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my summer student job days in the mid-70's , it was always to control the slump test to obtain the correct water ratio.

Of course aggregate moisture content can be easily measured with an added chemical gas  pressure and weighed sample, to predict the reduction of water required for an estimate.

That was my 2nd summer working for RKL in Winnipeg while the 1st yr was lab work doing modified Proctors and sieve analysis.